# csv.collator.py error with bash and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, macos, csv

I am trying to separate some data I have in a csv file into chunks using csv.collator.py. When I try to do it I seem to be getting some errors and I am not sure why or how to solve them.
This is the code:

```py
Ijeomas-MacBook-Pro:Heathrow data- 2019-02-07 till 2019-03-15 ijeoma$ csv_reader.py 15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo.csv | csv_collator.py -v -l 20 -u 100 -d 10 -f rh/15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo meteo.val.hmd
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_analysis/src/scs_analysis/csv_reader.py", line 99, in <module>
    for datum in reader.rows:
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_core/src/scs_core/csv/csv_reader.py", line 88, in rows
    datum = self.__header.as_dict([CSVReader.__recast(cell) for cell in row])
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_core/src/scs_core/csv/csv_dict.py", line 111, in as_dict
    raise ValueError("unmatched lengths: header: %s row: %s" % (self, row))
ValueError: unmatched lengths: header: CSVHeader:{cells:<generator object CSVHeader.__str__.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1100f7138>} row: ['rec', 'gases.Max of Time', 'gases.Average of praxis-431.val.NO2.cnc', 'gases.Average of praxis-431.val.NO.cnc', 'gases.Average of ref.NOCNC1 (Processed)', 'gases.Average of ref.NO2CNC1 (Processed)', 'gases.15 minute "real" data', 'meteo.val.hmd', 'meteo.val.tmp', 'meteo.tag', 'Error (C-G)', 'Praxis NO2 baselined']
csv_collator: CmdCSVCollator:{lower:20.0, upper:100.0, delta:10.0, file_prefix:rh/15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo, verbose:True, path:meteo.val.hmd}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_analysis/src/scs_analysis/csv_collator.py", line 71, in <module>
    collator = CSVCollator.construct(cmd.lower, cmd.upper, cmd.delta, cmd.file_prefix)
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_analysis/src/scs_analysis/helper/csv_collator.py", line 31, in construct
    bins.append(CSVCollatorBin.construct(bin_lower, bin_upper, file_prefix, form))
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_analysis/src/scs_analysis/helper/csv_collator.py", line 105, in construct
    writer = CSVWriter(file_name)
  File "/Users/ijeoma/SCS/scs_core/src/scs_core/csv/csv_writer.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.__file = open(self.__filename, "a" if self.__append else "w", newline='')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rh/15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo_020p0_030p0.csv'
Ijeomas-MacBook-Pro:Heathrow data- 2019-02-07 till 2019-03-15 ijeoma$
```

Comment: I made some changes please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469488/csv-collator-py-error-with-bash-and-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `ValueError: unmatched lengths` that appears on your stack trace seems that you are trying to set something with a value that exceeds its capability (ie: 20 values array inside 18 values array).

Also you have an `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rh/15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo_020p0_030p0.csv'`, so you should check that `15_min_Praxis_LHR2_meteo_020p0_030p0.csv` exists or that you have enough permmisions to access it.

Without some example code this is all I can help you :c

Hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Yes I changed the file name and that helped ill try to change the sizing too,  Thank you.

Comment: I have made a few changes and i can use the csv_collator however I wasn't able to get it to read data from the proposed file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469488/csv-collator-py-error-with-bash-and-python-3